# Proof strategy for Pointwise converging sequence of Riemann integrable functions to not uniformaly converge

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am wondering of a proof strategy to show. That a sequence of Riemann integrable functions which converges point wise to a function may not actually uniformly converge to it. If it makes the argument simpler i also know that the function $f$ the sequence of functions are converging point wise to, is not Riemann integrable. Although on a second thought is it possible to build such an argument without the knowledge of $f$ being non-Riemann integrable ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $f_n$ be the indicator function of the set $\{n,n+1,n+2,\ldots\}$, i.e. we have 
$$f_n= \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in \{n,n+1,n+2,\ldots\}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and note that each $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable (with integral $0$), and that $f_n\to 0$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Try}\ f_n=\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}.$$